# Library to Animate UITextView`lik a banner "a la" Music App

Tags: ios, uitextview, uianimation

I'm trying to have a `UITextView` reproducing the following effect (Apple Music App) :

[image: Image 1][image: Image 2]

The label `The Rolling Stones - Sweet Summer Sun, Live in Hyde Park ...` is too big fit in the view, and so it moving like a banner.

I'm looking for a library of a way to implement this effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this library [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel) I am sure it'll help you.

Comment: `MarqueeLabel`is a UILabel, where as `CBAutoScroolLayout` is a UIView. So `MarqueeLabel` is easier to use !

Answer (score 0):

I found an other good Library : 
[CBAutoScrollLabel](https://github.com/cbess/AutoScrollLabel)

I don't know with one is the best. I just implement `CBAutoScrollLabel`I'm it working perfectly.

A tips for some one who want to use it : **It's a UIView not a UITextView** (I've done the mistake in my Storyboard)